# Formatting off in Safari vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am using this [template](https://themeforest.net/item/salimo-creative-one-page-template/19128817) to build this [website](http://www.velodu.com).

In chrome and edge, the services tiles look right:

[image: correct]

In safari, the rows are messed up:

[image: wrong]

I am not a pro at this stuff ... I am just a freelancer trying to do everything ... and poked around and cannot spot the source of this problem.  The index.html and style.css code is pasted below.

[index.html header]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Velodu - Market Research & Consulting</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <!-- Template CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skins/purple.css" />
    <!-- Revolution Slider CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/plugins/revolution/css/settings.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/plugins/revolution/css/layers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/plugins/revolution/css/navigation.css" />
            <!-- Template JS Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
```

["Services" code in index.html]

```
        <!-- About Section Starts -->
        <section id="about" class="about">
            <!-- Container Starts -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Main Heading Starts -->
                <div class="text-center top-text">
                    <h1><span>About</span> Us</h1>
                    <h4>Who We Are</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Heading Ends -->
                <!-- Divider Starts -->
                <div class="divider text-center">
                    <span class="outer-line"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="outer-line"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- Divider Ends -->
                <!-- About Content Starts -->
                <div class="row about-content">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 about-left-side">
                        <p>Business keeps moving faster, so nobody has time for slow agencies who add complexity.</p>
                        <p>We deliver high-quality, high-velocity market research and consulting services because we are great at identifying and removing bottlenecks, especially when the bottleneck is us.</p>
                        <a class="custom-button scroll-to-target" href="#services">Our Services</a>
                        <div>
                            <p><br /></p>
                            <a style="color:#795DB4" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/garypansino/">Founder's LinkedIn Profile</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 about-right-side">
                        <div class="full-image-container hovered">
                            <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block" src="img/about.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="full-image-overlay">
                                <h3>Why <strong>Choose Us</strong></h3>
                                <ul class="list-why-choose-us">
                                    <li>Diverse experience across tech, CPG, retail, etc.</li>
                                    <li>Deep knowledge of research methodologies</li>
                                    <li>Strategic business lens</li>
                                    <li>Leverage the latest tools and tech</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- About Content Ends -->
            </div>
            <!-- Container Ends -->
        </section>
        <!-- About Section Ends -->        <!-- Services Section Starts -->
        <section id="services" class="services">
            <!-- Container Starts -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Main Heading Starts -->
                <div class="text-center top-text">
                    <h1><span>Our</span> Services</h1>
                    <h4>What We Do</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Heading Starts -->
                <!-- Divider Starts -->
                <div class="divider text-center">
                    <span class="outer-line"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="outer-line"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- Divider Ends -->
                <!-- Services Starts -->
                <div class="row services-box">
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-bar-chart" data-headline="Quantitative Research"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <!-- Service Item Content Starts -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-bar-chart">
                            <h2>Quantitative Research</h2>
                            <p>Of course we do surveys.  Concept tests, attitude and usage studies, pricing studies, brand tracking ... the list is long.  We do them better because of our advanced programming, and dashboarding skills that complement our deep methodological knowledge.</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Service Item Content Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-comments-o" data-headline="Qualitative Research"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <!-- Service Item Content Starts -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-comments-o">
                            <h2>Qualitative Research</h2>
                            <p>We're experts at setting up and conducting interviews, ethnographical research, and focus groups.  At the end, you'll get concise insights that tell a strategic story, rather than a text-heavy mess that you have to decipher yourself.</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Service Item Content Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-search" data-headline="Secondary Research"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <!-- Service Item Content Starts -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-search">
                            <h2>Secondary Research</h2>
                            <p>The best data is data that already exists.  Let us help you find information that is already out there, and compile it in a story that inspires action.</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Service Item Content Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-puzzle-piece" data-headline="Innovation"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-puzzle-piece">
                            <h2>Innovation</h2>
                            <p>Achieve breakthrough results by defining your problem, vision, hypotheses, experiments, etc. in addition to developing new concepts.  We help you add structure to the innovation process so it is more efficient and fruitful.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-sticky-note" data-headline="Facilitation"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <!-- Service Item Content Starts -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-sticky-note">
                            <h2>Facilitation</h2>
                            <p>Running a good meeting or workshop requires preparation and reflection time, which you may not have to devote.  Let us help you with your next brainstorming, team-building, or alignment-gathering session.</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Service Item Content Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                    <!-- Service Item Starts -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 services-box-item">
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Starts -->
                        <span class="services-box-item-cover fa fa-question-circle" data-headline="Other"></span>
                        <!-- Service Item Cover Ends -->
                        <!-- Service Item Content Starts -->
                        <div class="services-box-item-content fa fa-question-circle">
                            <h2>Other</h2>
                            <p>Have another need?  Surprise us with a new request.</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Service Item Content Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Service Item Ends -->
                </div>
                <!-- Services Ends -->
            </div>

</body>

</html>
```

["Services" code in style.css]

```
/* Services
---------------------------------------- */

.services {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.services .services-box {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.services .services-box:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.services .services-box:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.services .services-box-item {
    position: relative;
    color: #717c8e;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-perspective: 750px;
    -ms-perspective: 750px;
    -o-perspective: 750px;
    perspective: 750px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    float: left;
}
.services .services-box-item:hover,
.services .services-box-item:focus,
.services .services-box-item.hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.services .services-box-item:hover> .services-box-item-cover,
.services .services-box-item:focus> .services-box-item-cover,
.services .services-box-item.hover> .services-box-item-cover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.services .services-box-item:hover> .services-box-item-content,
.services .services-box-item:focus> .services-box-item-content,
.services .services-box-item.hover> .services-box-item-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
.services .services-box-item-cover,
.services .services-box-item-content {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.services .services-box-item-cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #ddd;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.services .services-box-item-cover:before,
.services .services-box-item-cover:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.services .services-box-item-cover:before {
    margin: -40px 0px 0px -20px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.services .services-box-item-cover:after {
    content: attr(data-headline);
    font-family: "Raleway";
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.services .services-box-item-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -16px -6px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.services .services-box-item-content:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: -60px;
    font-size: 228px;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.services .services-box-item-content h2 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: Capitalize;
}
.services .services-box-item-content p {
    line-height: 23px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 12px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.services[data-icon]:before,
.services[class^="icon-"]:before,
.services[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-indent: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.services[data-icon]:before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
}
.services[data-icon].after:before {
    content: none;
}
.services[data-icon].after:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-indent: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Any ideas/help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with more googling.

This great [article](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw/issues/58).

I replaced this in style.css:

```
.services .services-box:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.services .services-box:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

With this:

```
.services .services-box:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.services .services-box:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

And problem solved.